# In ActiveAdmin, posting to a collection_action is being attended, actually, by the :create member action

Tags: ruby-on-rails, activeadmin

I have this ActiveAdmin registration

```
ActiveAdmin.register User do
  permit_params :first_name, :last_name, :email, :role

  scope :all
  scope :admin
  scope :professor
  scope :student

  config.clear_action_items!

  index do
    id_column
    column :name do |c|
      c.full_name
    end
    column :email
    column :created_at do |c|
      c.created_at.strftime("%Y-%m-%d %H:%M")
    end
    column :role
    column :login_as do |c|
      link_to "login as", login_as_admin_user_path(c.id)
    end
    actions defaults: false do |c|
      item 'Show', admin_user_path(c.id)
      span '  |  '
      item 'Edit', edit_admin_user_path(c.id)
    end
  end

  filter :first_name
  filter :last_name
  filter :email

  form do |f|
    f.inputs do
      f.input :first_name
      f.input :last_name
      f.input :email
      if f.object.new_record?
        f.input :role, as: :select, collection: [['Professor', :professor], ['Student', :student]]
      elsif f.object.admin?
        f.input :role, as: :readonly, display: 'Administrator'
      else
        f.input :role, as: :select, collection: [['Professor', :professor], ['Student', :student], ['Administrator', :admin]]
      end
    end
    f.actions
  end

  action_item :only => :index do
    link_to 'Invite User', new_admin_user_path
  end

  action_item :only => :index do
    link_to 'Bulk Invite Users', bulk_new_admin_users_path
  end

  collection_action :bulk_new, method: :get do
    # Just render - no specific implementation
  end

  collection_action :bulk_create, method: :post do
    # Also tried: raise StandardError.new 'foo'
    render nothing: true
  end

  member_action :create, method: :post do
    pparams = permitted_params[:user]
    @user = User.new(pparams)
    if @user.admin?
      flash[:error] = 'Cannot invite admin users with this method'
      render :new
    else
      @user.avoid_password_validation = true
      if @user.valid?
        @user.invite!(current_user)
        redirect_to admin_user_path(@user.id), notice: "Invitation sent to email: #{@user.email}"
      else
        render :new
      end
    end
  end

  member_action :login_as do
    new_user = User.find(params[:id])
    session["admin_user_id"] = current_user.id
    sign_in(:user, new_user)
    redirect_to root_path
  end

  member_action :resend_activation do
    @user = User.find(params[:id])
    @user.send_confirmation_instructions
  end

  show do
    attributes_table :id, :first_name, :last_name, :email, :role, :encrypted_password, :reset_password_oken, :reset_password_sent_at, :remember_created_at,
                     :sign_in_count, :current_sign_in_at, :last_sign_in_at, :current_sign_in_ip, :last_sign_in_ip, :invitation_token, :invitation_created_at,
                     :invitation_sent_at, :invitation_accepted_at, :invitation_limit, :invited_by, :invited_by_type, :invitations_count, :created_at, 
                     :updated_at
  end
end
```

And my routes are generated like this:

```
                         admin_user POST   /admin/users/:id(.:format)                              admin/users#create
                login_as_admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id/login_as(.:format)                     admin/users#login_as
       resend_activation_admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id/resend_activation(.:format)            admin/users#resend_activation
               bulk_new_admin_users GET    /admin/users/bulk_new(.:format)                         admin/users#bulk_new
            bulk_create_admin_users POST   /admin/users/bulk_create(.:format)                      admin/users#bulk_create
           batch_action_admin_users POST   /admin/users/batch_action(.:format)                     admin/users#batch_action
                        admin_users GET    /admin/users(.:format)                                  admin/users#index
                                    POST   /admin/users(.:format)                                  admin/users#create
                     new_admin_user GET    /admin/users/new(.:format)                              admin/users#new
                    edit_admin_user GET    /admin/users/:id/edit(.:format)                         admin/users#edit
                                    GET    /admin/users/:id(.:format)                              admin/users#show
                                    PATCH  /admin/users/:id(.:format)                              admin/users#update
                                    PUT    /admin/users/:id(.:format)                              admin/users#update
                                    DELETE /admin/users/:id(.:format)                              admin/users#destroy
```

When I reach the `/admin/users/bulk_new` route, which is just a form hitting `/admin/users/bulk_create` (Url: `bulk_create_admin_users_path`, I can verify that for true in the browser itself, with no url wrapping or anything like that meddling), it displays as expected.

However, when I submit (also checking in the browser's Network tab to check no redirections exist - the url is `/admin/users/bulk_create`), the post request is handled by the `:create` member action (which fails since no user data was provided) instead of being handled by the `:bulk_create` collection action.

What am I missing here

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like an issue with the routes, based on output of `rake routes` the first of them `admin_user POST   /admin/users/:id(.:format)                              admin/users#create` have the same format as the one you want to use as bulk_create, and rails is taking as `:id` `bulk_create`